# Fitnesse : Testing was interrupted and results are incomplete. Test Pages:

Tags: fitnesse

I am new to the fitnesse framework. I create the test using the  https://schuchert.wikispaces.com/FitNesse.Tutorials.1 link. 
But I am getting the following error while running it.

**Testing was interrupted and results are incomplete. Test Pages: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions     Assertions: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions (0.052 seconds)
Unable to start test system 'fit': java.lang.NullPointerException**

Kindly help.

Comment: Please post your test page and your Java code.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this same error recently whilst using DbFit version 3.1.0 which uses FitNesse v20140903 under the hood.  I resolved this by adding the following to my root page ...

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {java -cp %p %m}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before first test table you should add three important lines:

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\Probjects\HelloWorld\binary\NetRunner.Executable.exe}
!path C:\Probjects\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\FitNesseHelloWorld.dll
```

First describes the command pattern (for Java - {java -cp %p %m} )
Second has path to the runner (I'm not sure that it is required for Java application)
Third has path to the your test library (to the your jar file)

https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Create-the-first-test

I could catch this error on my local environment. Please check the path to the your Runner, because the same error is presented if the path is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by adding the following in root page

```
!define CLASSPATH_PROPERTY {CLASSPATH}
```

Also removed the `-cp %p`

After that it started working